# How to force to draw shadows in Xcode Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm using Xcode 7 to design my app but have a troubles with displaying shadows in design time.

```
@IBDesignable class MyView : UIView {

@IBInspectable var shadowColor : UIColor? {
    get {
        return UIColor(CGColor: self.layer.shadowColor!);
    }
    set {
        self.layer.shadowColor = newValue?.CGColor;
    }
}

 @IBInspectable var shadowRadius : Double {
    get {
        return Double(self.layer.shadowRadius);
    }
    set {
        self.layer.shadowRadius = CGFloat(newValue);
    }
}


@IBInspectable var shadowOpacity : Float {
    get {
        return layer.shadowOpacity;
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowOpacity = newValue;
    }
}

@IBInspectable var shadowOffset : CGSize {
    get {
        return layer.shadowOffset;
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowOffset = newValue;
    }
}
```

}

In iOS Simulator and devices shadows draw well, but in design time they don't.

Is it possible to show shadows in design time?